# Custom Taxonomy Filtering with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ive been trying to figure this out for three days now, even using solutions on this site. I still cant get this working.

I have a wordpress loop that uses a filter to show posts by post type. Now the post type is called "case-studies" Thus all the posts in the type case studies are shown.

But i need to hide a specific taxonomy term from this loop. The taxonomy is called "sectors" and the term is "healthcare". Ive tried all manner of combinations but still cant get this. I need this pretty urgent. Anyone who can help would save my life.

Here is the query and the loop

```
<?php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=case-studies&posts_per_page=-1' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post(); 


?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('comercial', 'personal', 'etc') //excluding the term you dont want.
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I dind´t try it but you could just make a query calling only the terms you want, you could previously populate the terms array listing all the terms on the taxonomy and excluding the one you want, i think this is a little hacky it should be another straight forward way to do it but give it a try since it is a case of life or dead =).

source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: nope, didnt work, thanks though. Im sure ive tried this one already.

Comment: scrap that, this does work. my apologies, i had an error or two. problem is I have approx 20 different taxonomy terms and its not really dynamic enough.

Comment: although this is working at the moment. is there a way to query multiple taxonomy terms. "sectors & types"

Comment: If you folow the link i give you above you could see some example querying multiple taxonomies, the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$type = 'cpreviews';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Comment: can i assume that this query only omits the post type "cpreviews". Id like all the posts from the case-studies post type (cpreaviews) but to omit a particular taxonomy term within the "sector" taxonomy.

Comment: you can simply put a if condition... still if u have any doubts then let me know..

Comment: i have thought over and over about the if condition but my php knowledge is limited. could you expand please.

Answer (score 0):

ok then try this one it will extract your terms dinamicaly and exclude the term you dont want, i didn´t check if it is working but this is the logic, please check for sintax errors.

```
$terms = get_terms("sectors");
$count = count($terms);
$termsAr = array();
if ($count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->name !== "healthcare"){//Here we exclude the term or terms we dont want to show
            array_push($termsAr, $term->name);
        }
    }
}

$terms = get_terms("types");
$count = count($terms);
$termsAr2 = array();
if ($count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->name !== "healthcare"){//Here we exclude the term or terms we dont want to show
            array_push($termsAr2, $term->name);
        }
    }
}
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $termsAr //excluding the term you dont want.
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'types',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $termsAr2 //excluding the term you dont want.
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: This is getting better. The query seems to be working but to note: i have two taxonomies im trying to work with. I need to output all the posts from both the taxonomies "sectors" and "types". this is what im using at the moment. it does seem to be missing out some posts. im thinking that may be because there is a missing taxonomy "types"

Comment: Okay assuming you have the same term "healthcare" in taxonomy types and you want to exclude it too here is the example, i recomend a little more research on this because i think that there is a strightfoward way to do this, this is a little hacky just to get the job done for now.

Comment: By the way you could make a up vote on the answer if you find it use full it help me as a contributor, thanks.