# Display page of custom post type taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

Alright, so what I have is a Wordpress theme with a custom post type (listing) and custom taxonomies under that already built in. I've successfully added my own custom taxonomy (new-developments) under the existing custom post type.

I have also setup a custom template for the new taxonomy titled taxonomy-new-developments.php which functions as well, however, when attempting to get just those custom post types with the taxonomy "new-developments" displayed on their own pages I get all the posts with the custom post type "listing".

Here is my code:

customposttypes.php -

```
add_action('init', 'property_new_dev_taxonomies');
function property_new_dev_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy('new-developments',
        'listing',
        array (
        'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'New Developments',
                'singluar_name' => 'New Developments',
                'search_items' => 'Search New Developments',
                'popular_items' => 'Popular New Developments',
                'all_items' => 'All New Developments',
                'parent_item' => 'Parent New Development',
                'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent New Development:',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit New Development',
                'update_item' => 'Update New Development',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Development',
                'new_item_name' => 'New Developments',
        ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_tagcloud' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'new-developments'),
                'query_var' => 'new-developments',
                'public'=>true)
        );
}
```

the call in my taxonomy-new-developments.php

```
<?php $posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'listing', 'new-developments' 
    ) 
); ?>
```

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: something I left out, which is key to this issue is that the desired result is a page that displays the "new-developments" in a list (this works as you can see [here](http://citymiamihomes.com/new-developments/) )

Moving down the cascade of locations is where I have the problem, clicking on "Doral" which has one listing active brings up the problem page where all posts under the "listing" custom post type are displayed. This is what I need to figure out how to filter out to only display those under the "taxonomy" "location".

Comment: What are the terms that you want in this "new development" taxonomy?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert what I need to have is the "new developments" taxonomy display any of the current or future added children, currently they are "doral" and "brickell". So the filter that I have just showing the all of the "new developments" is working properly, it's when I get down to the next level to the city filters that it's not working and just including everything from the "listing" custom post type.

Sorry, this rather changes things, I am learning more about the problem as I'm moving along. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Reviewing this over the weekend and I've come to the realization that I'm not quite sure what the relation is between the taxonomy of **"new-developments" > "doral"**. Would it simply be a sub-category of the parent category? Whatever the terminology, this is the "item" that I am in need of isolating on the results page so as to get only the listings for Doral under the New Developments category. Again, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try with this code:

```
<?php
$type = 'New Developments';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Or go through this link:

[Custom Taxonomy Filtering with Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490762/custom-taxonomy-filtering-with-wordpress/19491604#19491604)

Thanks

Comment: I attempted to use your code however I ran into an error on line 9. Not being a php developer I attempted to fix it, and while I removed the error the code would not generate any results.

Comment: I ran the code here: [link]http://phpcodechecker.com/[/link] and this is the error it displayed: _Error: There is 1 more opening parenthesis '(' than expected
PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')' in your code on line 9
$my_query = null;_

Comment: It's missing a closing parenthesis on line 8.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert thanks for pointing that out, I did end up figuring out what the matter was but it didn't change the outcome of the code. Still got no results.